# Problems with using plotCalibration() from the predictABEL package in R

Tags: r, statistics, predict, calibration

I’ve been having some trouble with the plotCalibration() function, I have managed to get it to work before, but recently whilst working with another dataset ([here is a link to the .Rda data file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2deg5fbta65c95v/AAB_maPTZOSOqfEDnAtjWkmca?dl=0)), I have been unable to shake off an error message which keeps cropping up:

```
> plotCalibration(data = data, cOutcome = 2, predRisk = data$sortmort)

Error in plotCalibration(data = data, cOutcome = 2, predRisk = data$sortmort) : The specified outcome is not a binary variable.`
```

When I’ve tried to set the cOutcome column to factors or to logical, it still doesn’t work.

I’ve looked at the source of the function and the only time the error message comes up is in the first if()else{} statement:

```
if (length(unique(y))!=2) {stop(" The specified outcome is not a binary variable.\n")} 
else{
```

But I have checked that the length(unique(y)) is indeed ==2, and so don’t understand why the error message still crops up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data you sent earlier, I do not see any error though:

Following output were produced along with a calibration plot:

```
> library(PredictABEL)
> plotCalibration(data = data, cOutcome = 2, predRisk = data$sortmort)
$Table_HLtest
               total meanpred meanobs predicted observed
[0.000632,0.00129)   340    0.001   0.000      0.31        0
0.001287             198    0.001   0.000      0.25        0
[0.001374,0.00201)   283    0.002   0.004      0.53        1
0.002009             310    0.002   0.000      0.62        0
[0.002505,0.00409)   154    0.003   0.000      0.52        0
[0.004086,0.00793)   251    0.006   0.000      1.42        0
[0.007931,0.00998)   116    0.008   0.009      0.96        1
[0.009981,0.19545]   181    0.024   0.011      4.40        2

$Chi_square
```

[1] 4.906

```
$df
```

[1] 8

```
$p_value
```

[1] 0.7676

Comment: Thanks! I suspect there's a namespace or environment issue at play here. In which case I'll have to try removing other objects that might be in the environment when I'm working with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you're passing a dataframe to PlotCalibration. Passing a dplyr tibble can cause this error. Converting with the normal `as.data.frame()` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `table(data[,2],useNA = "ifany")` to see the number of levels of the outcome variable of your dataset.

The function `plotCalibration` will execute when the outcome is a binary variable (two levels).

Comment: I have confirmed that there are only 2 levels in the outcome variable: This is the result of using table(data[,2], useNA= "ifany):   ` 0    1 
1829    4 `

Comment: Great that you already tried that. This suggests length(unique(y)) should be 2, but you indicated before that "I have checked that the length(unique(y)) is indeed !=2". Why that is so?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo, should not have the **!**, should be **==** instead I've corrected it now.