# PredictABEL model calibration

Tags: binary

Please help

the plotCalibration give me this error" The specified outcome is not a binary variable." But it is!
How can mange this problem I'm not able to go further !

""## Load PredictABEL
library(PredictABEL)

### AIC mode

plotCalibration(data=cpain, cOutcome=1, predRisk = fitted(forward.aic))""

Error in plotCalibration(data = cpain, cOutcome = 1, predRisk = fitted(forward.aic)) :
The specified outcome is not a binary variable.""

Thanks
in advance

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012289/2029527), passing a `dplyr` tibble to the `plotCalibration()` function can cause this error. I also received this error when passing a `dplyr` tibble. As [suggested by Bob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012289/2029527), converting the data file with `as.data.frame()` worked for me. See below for how to do this:

```
cpain <- as.data.frame(cpain)
```